# Copy or move all files in a directory regardles of folder depth or number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, unix

Lets say i have a folder named Pictures and I want to move or copy all files out of this folder.

However I also want to move and harvest all of the files who are in sub folders so:
Pictures/1.png
Pictures/yolo/2.png
Pictures/yolo/swag/sand/3.png
Pictures/extra/fire/4.png

I want to move or copy all these files to another folder like results so I get:
results/1.png
results/2.png
results/3.png
results/4.png

Only I have no idea in advance what sub folders will be in the Pictures folder.

How can I accomplish this in bash/shell scripts ?
I also appreciate making it file type neutral so any files are harvested from their directories (not only .png like in my example) and I have no idea what the file name will be (I only used 1...4 because i did not have any idea how to name them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
find /absolute/path/to/Pictures -type f -name '*.png' -exec mv -i {} /absolute/path/to/results  \;
```

Another option is to use `xargs`

```
find /absolute/path/to/Pictures -name '*.png' | xargs -I files mv files /absolute/path/to/results
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed I modified your answer so that it can take all files.
`find ./pictures -name '*.*' | xargs -I files mv files ./results`
I also removed the need for absolute paths, it works this way also.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `copy` all files and subdirectories along with their contents using cp's `recursive` option:

```
cp -pr <source_path>/* <destination_path>/
```

But, `moving` them recursively is a bit tricky, you will need to create `tar` files of the subdirectories and move them and then `untar` the tar files in destination path. As this is a complex process, as a workaround, you can copy the files/directories recursively and then delete the files from original path.

```
cp -pr <source_path>/* <destination_path>/ && rm -rf <source_path>/*
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I wanted. In your code the directory structure is copied.
I wanted to strip away the directory structure.